# Rails Paperclip handle CMYK images. How to detect current colorspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, image-processing, paperclip

I am using Paperclip to handle all files uploads in my project. My problem is that some files are images and some images are using CMYK as colorspace and that is a problem in some browsers, but specially on some Android versions (for example Android 4.2 can't handle jpgs with CMYK colorspace)

I solved that by using convert_options in paperclip and remove CMYK and add RGB. My code looks like that:

```
has_attached_file :media,
                  :storage => :azure,
                  :styles => lambda { |a|
                      if a.instance.is_image?
                        {
                            :thumb => {geometry: "75x75#", convert_options: '-strip -colorspace RGB' },
                            :preview => {geometry: "300x300#",convert_options: '-strip -colorspace RGB' },
                            :original => {convert_options: '-strip -colorspace RGB'}

                        }
                      else ....
```

That works fine, however when running convert_options there is an alteration of colors. So, I would want to run convert_options only if I detect that current colorspace is CMYK and do not run it if it is already RGB, it is doing nothing for already RGB images, just alters the original colors.
I am looking for something like:

```
    has_attached_file :media,
                      :storage => :azure,
                      :styles => lambda { |a|
                        if a.instance.is_image?
                          if a.instance.colorspace_is?("CMYK")
                                {
                                    :thumb => {geometry: "75x75#", convert_options: '-strip -colorspace RGB' },
                                    :preview => {geometry: "300x300#",convert_options: '-strip -colorspace RGB' },
                                    :original => {convert_options: '-strip -colorspace RGB'}
                          else
                                {
                                    :thumb => "75x75#",
                                    :preview => "300x300#"}

                                }
                          end
                         else ....
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

In lib/paperclip I added colorspace.rb with this code inside

```
module Paperclip
  class Colorspace < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      scale, crop = @current_geometry.transformation_to(@target_geometry, crop?)
      trans = []
      trans << "-coalesce" if animated?
      trans << "-auto-orient" if auto_orient
      trans << "-resize" << %["#{scale}"] unless scale.nil? || scale.empty?
      trans << "-crop" << %["#{crop}"] << "+repage" if crop
      trans << '-layers "optimize"' if animated?
      trans << "-strip -colorspace RGB" unless is_rgb?
      trans
    end

    protected
    def is_rgb?
        colorspace = identify("-verbose %m :file | grep 'Colorspace'", :file => "#{@file.path}[0]").to_s.downcase.strip
        colorspace && colorspace.include?("rgb")
    rescue Cocaine::ExitStatusError => e
      return false
    rescue Cocaine::CommandNotFoundError => e
      raise Paperclip::Errors::CommandNotFoundError.new("Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.")
    end

  end
end
```

and in my model I set processor to colorspace instead of thumbnail. Works great